# How to connect sensor to PC?

Tags: design, signal, hardware

I have made a sensor that produces a 4 bit output. I want to perform some logic based on patterns.

I was thinking if somehow I could give that 4 bit input to my computer, I could then write code to perform logic. But, the problem is, I have no idea how to do this.

How can I give a 4 bit input to the computer? Can I use USB or some other hardware?

Comment: How fast does the sensor output change? How quickly after the sensor output changes do you need to complete the calculation?

Comment: The sensor changes its state after every 5 second. I just want to perform some simple logic like if input is "1100" display "Some alert" etc.

Comment: You should easily be able to do this with an off-the-shelf product. Search for "USB GPIO".

Comment: related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61290/usb-to-gpio-module

Comment: How are your 4 bits represented? What ports does your computer have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any IO port available on your computer. PCI(e), USB, Ethernet, parallel ports, RS-232, PS/2, game port, Firewire...you *could* use any of them, provided they are fast enough for the rate of data you must transfer.

If you want *easy*, the [parallel port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) is the way to go. These are trivial to interface to TTL. Though, they are quite uncommon these days.

RS-232 is also pretty easy. You can use [MAX232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf) to generate the +/- 12V signaling, and a UART (included in most microcontrollers) to build circuitry that speaks RS-232. Serial ports are also becoming quite uncommon. One solution is to use a USB <-> RS-232 IC like those made by [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/), either by including one of their ICs in your circuit, or buying a [pre-made cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=ftdi+cable) with the FTDI IC included. This is how the Arduino implements its "USB" connection.

You can also use the [RS-232 control lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Signals) as a [bit-bang interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging#External_links) if you don't need high speeds.

There are also any number of data acquisition peripherals. Some have PCIe interfaces and are extremely fast and expensive. Some cost a few dollars on eBay and may have a USB interface. Without knowing more about your requirements it's impossible to make a specific recommendation.